# web page aesthetics for address validation

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm asking more of a CSS question I want to design my webpage since all of the  functionalities are now working, as you can see in the image below my webpage is quite plain. How can I improve the my webpage to make it more pleasing. Any suggestions, Opinions and CSS sites are appreciated tnx.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for graphic design work.

Comment: I don't think this question is suitable for stackoverflow...

Comment: this article might interest you: [click me](http://www.noupe.com/design/the-keys-to-making-fresh-forwardly-aesthetic-web-designs.html)

Comment: That's the job of an UI/UX designer

Comment: Sir @FabrizioCalderan and Quentin I'm sorry this is my first time asking a css/design related question if it seems of topic and not suited, I'll be willing to move it to its designated place if you can redirect me :)

Comment: This question is probably better suited for UX: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sir @Fishbowl thank you sir I'll move it, will I just delete this or is there a way to move it without deleting this one

Comment: You'll need to recreate it.  Also I would reword the question to make it more specific because they probably won't like it in its current form over there either.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just flag our mods to delete it because I can't delete it myself since it already has some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to improve your app design, IMO, is to ask a pool of potential users what they think and how will they use.

See http://www.uxteam.com/blog/focus-groups-vs-usability-testing/

DISCLAIMER : but maybe not here in SO :-)